# Wrapping a parent and its children with Wordpress Walker

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to wrap a parent and its children in another element when using Walker and `wp_list_pages`, so I could operate them as a block?

Currently I'm using code

```
class My_Walker extends Walker {
  var $db_fields = array(
    'parent' => 'post_parent',
    'id' => 'ID',
  );

  public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $output .= "<nav class=\"list\">\n";
  }

  public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $output .= "</nav>\n";
  }

  public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    $class = 'list-item';
    if ( $args['has_children'] ) {
      $class ='list-title-item';
    }

    $output .= "<a href=\"#$item->ID\" class=\"$class\">$item->post_title</a>\n";
  }
}
```

which produces

```
<a href="#116" class="list-title-item">Parent 1</a>
<nav class="list">
  <a href="#118" class="list-item">Child 1.1</a>
  <a href="#120" class="list-item">Child 1.2</a>
  <a href="#122" class="list-item">Child 1.3</a>
</nav>
<a href="#125" class="list-title-item">Parent 2</a>
<nav class="list">
  <a href="#127" class="list-item">Child 2.1</a>
  <a href="#132" class="list-item">Child 2.2</a>
</nav>
```

What I would like to get is

```
<div id="title-116" class="list-title">
  <a href="#116" class="list-title-item">Parent 1</a>
  <nav class="list">
    <a href="#118" class="list-item">Child 1.1</a>
    <a href="#120" class="list-item">Child 1.2</a>
    <a href="#122" class="list-item">Child 1.3</a>
  </nav>
</div>
<div id="title-125" class="list-title">
  <a href="#125" class="list-title-item">Parent 2</a>
  <nav class="list">
    <a href="#127" class="list-item">Child 2.1</a>
    <a href="#132" class="list-item">Child 2.2</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I'm calling wp_list_pages with the code

```
wp_list_pages( array(
  'child_of' => $page_id,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'order' => 'asc',
  'depth' => 2,
  'walker' => new My_Walker,
) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `<div>` to the `start_el` and `end_el` methods, only for top-level items. (i.e. depth = 0)

```
public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    $class = 'list-item';
    if ( $args['has_children'] ) {
      $class ='list-title-item';
    }

    $divopen = '';
    if (0 === $depth) {
        $divopen = "<div id=\"title-{$item->ID}\" class=\"list-title\">";
    }

    $output .= "$divopen\r\n<a href=\"#$item->ID\" class=\"$class\">$item->post_title</a>\n";
}

public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    ...
    // Whatever else output is, plus:
    if (0 === $depth) {   
        $output .= "</div>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Modify the Walker Class:

class Custom_Nav_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = null) {
        // Add a sub-menu wrapper with a class for styling
        $output .= '<ul class="sub-menu">';
    }

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = null, $id = 0) {
        // Add a class to the list item based on the depth
        if ($depth === 0) {
            $output .= '<li class="menu-item menu-parent-item">';
        } elseif ($depth === 1) {
            $output .= '<li class="menu-item menu-child-item">';
        } else {
            $output .= '<li class="menu-item menu-grandchild-item">';
        }

        // Add the menu item content
        $output .= '<a href="' . esc_url($item->url) . '">' . esc_html($item->title) . '</a>';

        // Close the list item
        $output .= '</li>';
    }
}

----------
Add JavaScript Code:
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Toggle submenu display on click of parent menu items
    $('.menu-item-has-children > a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('submenu-open');
    });
});
Update CSS Styles:
.menu-item .sub-menu {
    display: none;
}

.menu-item.submenu-open > .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
```